# Field 'Type' in Contacts -> GetFields API

Tags: contacts, api, contact-types

What does the 'type' refer to in the results of 'getfields' action of the Contact Entity. It has a numeric value (1,2, 16 etc). Below are a few sample results.

```
        "id": {
        "name": "id",
        "type": 1,
        "title": "Contact ID",
        "description": "Unique Contact ID",
        "required": true,
        "import": true,
        "where": "civicrm_contact.id",
        "headerPattern": "/internal|contact?|id$/i",
        "export": true,
        "table_name": "civicrm_contact",
        "entity": "Contact",
        "bao": "CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact",
        "localizable": 0,
        "add": "1.1",
        "is_core_field": true,
        "api.aliases": [
            "contact_id"
        ]
    },
    "contact_type": {
        "name": "contact_type",
        "type": 2,
        "title": "Contact Type",
        "description": "Type of Contact.",
        "maxlength": 64,
        "size": 30,
        "where": "civicrm_contact.contact_type",
        "export": true,
        "contactType": null,
        "table_name": "civicrm_contact",
        "entity": "Contact",
        "bao": "CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact",
        "localizable": 0,
        "html": {
            "type": "Select",
            "maxlength": 64,
            "size": 30
        },
        "pseudoconstant": {
            "table": "civicrm_contact_type",
            "keyColumn": "name",
            "labelColumn": "label",
            "condition": "parent_id IS NULL"
        },
        "add": "1.1",
        "is_core_field": true
    },
    "contact_sub_type": {
        "name": "contact_sub_type",
        "type": 2,
        "title": "Contact Subtype",
        "description": "May be used to over-ride contact view and edit templates.",
        "maxlength": 255,
        "size": 45,
        "import": true,
        "where": "civicrm_contact.contact_sub_type",
        "headerPattern": "/C(ontact )?(subtype|sub-type|sub type)/i",
        "export": true,
        "table_name": "civicrm_contact",
        "entity": "Contact",
        "bao": "CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact",
        "localizable": 0,
        "serialize": 1,
        "html": {
            "type": "Select",
            "maxlength": 255,
            "size": 45
        },
        "pseudoconstant": {
            "table": "civicrm_contact_type",
            "keyColumn": "name",
            "labelColumn": "label",
            "condition": "parent_id IS NOT NULL"
        },
        "add": "1.5",
        "is_core_field": true
    },
    "do_not_email": {
        "name": "do_not_email",
        "type": 16,
        "title": "Do Not Email",
        "import": true,
        "where": "civicrm_contact.do_not_email",
        "headerPattern": "/d(o )?(not )?(email)/i",
        "dataPattern": "/^\\d{1,}$/",
        "export": true,
        "default": "0",
        "table_name": "civicrm_contact",
        "entity": "Contact",
        "bao": "CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact",
        "localizable": 0,
        "html": {
            "type": "CheckBox"
        },
        "add": "1.1",
        "is_core_field": true
    }
```

Comment: I suspect it's the contact type and/or or contact sub type? Api v4 let's you select the load options so try with setting to   'id', 'name', 'label'  - mine returned:         "id": "Household",
        "label": "Household",
        "name": "Household"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` is the data type - eg Integer, String, Boolean.

If you use APIv4 `Contact.getfields` returns `data_type` with more obvious strings.  For example:

```
"data_type": "Integer"

"data_type": "String",
```